# When does Wonder Woman learn this is how she was created?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-2017

[This article](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/06/wonder-woman-movie-easter-egg-father-zeus-clay-bondage/amp) claims that.

> Diana learns in the 2017 Wonder Woman film that she was created as the result of sexual intercourse between Zeus and Hippolyta.

**Which scene in the 2017 Wonder Woman film contained this revelation?**

I do not recall this revelation despite having seen the movie a few times.  Please give the exact scene so that I can look for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Towards the end of the movie when Diana finally confronts Ares in the recon tower he tells her that she is the daughter of Hippolyta and Zeus. Whether thats 100% true is wishy washy and Hippolyta told her a different story, and her origin from the comics are slightly different as well.

Comment: I definitely do see that your answer must be the scene to which the author of the article is referring.  But the scene in question fails to communicate that anything sexual was involved. These are gods who can breath life into clay together as easily as they could f***.  Thank you and+1 for isolating the scene.

Comment: It doesn't deviate from the comics, it was retconned to be this way in nu52 continuity and I believe has been built upon for Rebirth continuity

Comment: If you know anything about Greek Mythology, you know that Zeus will always opt for f***ing over any other form of life creation, given the opportunity. And sometimes, even if _not_ given an opportunity.

Comment: @CodeMed In the context of Greek mythology, any reference to Zeus fathering someone pretty strongly communicates sex. For that matter, more often than not, it's probable that he took on an animal form for said ..... fathering.